# Why Facebook didn't just copy Instagram which wasn't patented?

Tags: idea, websites, facebook, safety

Facebook bought Instagram when it wasn't patented. Facebook could have just created a copy of Instagram and launched It with their already existing millions of users.

1- Why did Facebook pay 1 Billion dollars for a product that can be replicated without patent issues ?

2- And Is It "safe" to launch a new website or an idea  without a patent and without the big companies just overtaking It ?

Comment: It isn't just features. It is users who are signed up to it and who have feelings of belonging to it. And patents are a business tool. Sometimes first mover advantages and trademark are more valuable.

Comment: 1 and 2 are out of scope for this site and 3 is marginal.

Comment: You don't get a patent on a website. You might get a patent on some specific feature on a website if it meets the requirements of a patent. That said, just about none of this question is on-topic for this site. You might try the Law SE site or perhaps some business focussed site.